# Blocking access to addon domains

Tags: cpanel, addon-domain

I'm using cpanel to create addon domains for my account, the addon domains are created so that `addon.com` is put in the path `/home/user/public_html/addon.com/` which means I can access them via `primarydomain.com/addon.com`.  I'd like to cut off access to these directories so people can't access them outside of their domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in your **.htaccess** file at the **root** of **addon.com**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.primarydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ path/to/404/ErrorDoc
```

**Alternative and far better:** while creating **addon.com** specify the **document root** as outside the **public_html** folder. ie. **/addon.com** instead of **/public_html/addon.com**.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

use htaccess and look at hostname and redirect if it wrong